# Map SQL Server Commands

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-management

I'm new with SQL Server (already used MySQL on Linux though). I have a database that is always using the maximum limit on my Windows Server. I've already limited the amount of maximum memory, but my application is slow.

How do I find out which SQL command/string is using my memory?

Answer (score 0):

Real time memory usage tracking can be done by setting up counters in Perfmon.  It's a bit cumbersome to set those up, so if you're OK with running a query to see a fixed point in time, then Glenn Berry has a very comprehensive set of memory diagnostic queries that I use on our SQL Server 2012 database.

https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/sql-server-memory-related-queries/

The specific query to use in your situation depends on if you're looking for a query or a stored procedure.

Looking for a query:

```
-- Find single-use, ad-hoc queries that are bloating the plan cache
SELECT TOP(100) [text], cp.size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan' 
AND cp.objtype = N'Adhoc' 
AND cp.usecounts = 1
ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC;
```

Looking for a stored procedure:

```
-- Top Cached SPs By Total Logical Reads (SQL 2008 and 2008 R2). Logical reads relate to memory pressure
SELECT TOP(25) p.name AS [SP Name], qs.total_logical_reads AS                [TotalLogicalReads], 
qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS     [AvgLogicalReads],qs.execution_count, 
ISNULL(qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Second, qs.cached_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS     [Calls/Second], 
qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count 
AS [avg_elapsed_time], qs.cached_time
FROM sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS qs
ON p.[object_id] = qs.[object_id]
WHERE qs.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC;
```